# How do i get order notes using PHP with the woocommerce REST API json response

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, woocommerce

I'm trying to follow http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#list-all-order-notes to get order notes from my orders and get the author and id inside a nested json respons but it's not working

Does anything stand out as being wrong here?

```
require_once 'auth.php';

$notes = $woocommerce->get('orders/108668/notes');
$json = json_decode($notes, true);

foreach($json as $elem)  {
   echo($elem['id']. ", ".$elem['author'] );
   echo("<br/>");
}
```

If i `print_r($notes);` I get the response like so

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 24721 [author] => haspden [date_created] => 2020-12-07T09:03:01 [date_c........`

if i `print_r($json);` i get nothing :/

Any thouhgts? I'm sure it something obvious and due to my missunderstanding between arrays and objects with json.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try casting `$notes` with `array` and expose it as json using `json_encode`:

```php
$notes = $woocommerce->get('orders/108668/notes');
header('Content-Type: application/json'); // this line is to make sure the output format is JSON
echo json_encode((array)$notes);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from what you supplied, the response from `$notes = $woocommerce->get('orders/108668/notes');` is already an array and you can loop through it and do whatever you like. You don't need to json_decode it.

Moreover, json_decode first parameter is string as the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) says but you supplied an array.